# Sort string array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an ID:Name Array

example:

```
$datas = array();
$datas[2345] = "Banana";
$datas[5740] = "Apple";
$datas[98763]= "Orange";
```

My final but is to sort the array alphabetically.

```
var_dump($datas);
//"4536" => "Apple", "2345" => Banana", "98763" => "Orange"
```

I try with usort but it's not working.

```
 usort($datas, function ($a, $b) {
            return strcasecmp($a,$b);
        });
```

How can I sort alphabetically that king of arrays?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: Also, hint: `usort($datas, 'strcasecmp')`. No need for the anonymous function wrapper.

Comment: @deceze I think instead of `usort` OP needs to use `uasort`

Comment: @Narendra Yeah, probably, but let's stop guessing and have the OP *tell* us exactly what "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) from php array functions

Please refer [Array Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

```
    <?php
    $datas = array();
    $datas[2345] = "Banana";
    $datas[5740] = "Apple";
    $datas[98763]= "Orange";

    asort($datas);

    print_r($datas);
    //Array ( [5740] => Apple [2345] => Banana [98763] => Orange )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [asort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.asort.php) function:

```
asort($datas);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a `usort` simply use `asort` as

```
asort($datas);
```

Or you can simply use `uasort` instead of `usort` as you need to have your keys also so simply use as

```
uasort($datas,'strcasecmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

`asort` is what you're looking for, it will sort it alphabetically as you can see below.

```
$datas = array();
$datas[2345] = "Banana";
$datas[5740] = "Apple";
$datas[98763]= "Orange";

asort($datas);

var_dump($datas);

array(3) { [5740]=> string(5) "Apple" [2345]=> string(6) "Banana" [98763]=> string(6) "Orange" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
asort();
```

[From PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is
>   used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element
>   order is significant.

```
$datas = array();
$datas[2345] = "Banana";
$datas[5740] = "Apple";
$datas[98763]= "Orange";

asort($datas);
```

Now when you wish to see the output with `var_dump($datas);` you'd see:

```
array(3) {[5740]=> string(5) "Apple" [2345]=> string(6) "Banana" [98763]=> string(6) "Orange"}
```